# How to show a part of a FlowDocument?

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I need to shorten a FlowDocument which is shown in a FlowDocumentScrollViewer.

shows: **Lorem** *ipsum* dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.

should show: **Lorem** *ipsu*...

How can I do this?

Comment: can u post code which u have tried to solve the problem? just a friendly reminder: At SO you should try to atleast find a solution and then if u r stuck u can post the code to ask for help :) ...

Comment: @na th: I do not think that SO is only to find bugs or improve the code. There are thousands WHY/HOW questions being asked and answered everyday! The question is how to trim a FlowDocument "without losing its format".

Comment: I used TextRange. But the text formatting is lost after trimming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as the following. The FlowDocument is trimmed if it is longer than "maxLength":

```
var wholeTextRange = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);
if (wholeTextRange.Text.Length > maxLength)
{
    TextPointer endPos = doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(maxLength);
    var textRange = new TextRange(endPos, doc.ContentEnd);
    textRange.Text = "...";
}
```